# Android Development - Custom view classes can not be instantiated

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am using the [codly.io](http://coldy.io) plugin that allows me to convert .PSD into Android XML.

However once exported, the custom views that are created PercentageLayout 
can not be instantiated.

I believe this is causing the UI to not fit the screens properly.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.BridgeContext cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
at io.codly.components.PercentageLayout.<init>(PercentageLayout.java:58)
at io.codly.components.PercentageLayout.<init>(PercentageLayout.java:43)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:413)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:105)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallback.loadView(LayoutlibCallback.java:176)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:207)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:132)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:400)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:332)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:350)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService$5.compute(RenderService.java:708)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService$5.compute(RenderService.java:697)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:932)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:697)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.render(RenderService.java:816)
at com.intellij.android.designer.designSurface.AndroidDesignerEditorPanel$6.run(AndroidDesignerEditorPanel.java:480)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:327)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Does `PercentageLayout` implement `Activity`?

Comment: @SashaSalauyou extends Relative Layout

Comment: This is `View`, not `Activity`.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou The PercentageLayout class does not implement any class

Comment: Error message definitely says you try to use `RelativeLayout` as  `Activity`

Comment: @SashaSalauyou   ((Activity)context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics); also, activity is imported in the PercentageLayout class.

Comment: You need to fix that code manually, or (try to) file a codly issue.

Comment: The references to intellij in your stack trace indicate that this is occurring **during your IDE's attempt to preview** your layout, not at runtime.  Making a custom view class that will work on the device, and making one that will work in the preview are two different things.  If you merely switch to the code or textual view of the layout (ie, not having the IDE try to preview it for you), build, and deploy the app things may be fine.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I tested the app on a device and the view does not seem to match....

Comment: What do you mean by "match"?  If you are having an issue with the run on the device, post the stack trace from the device captured via logcat - not the one you have here, which is from the IDE layout preview.  If it's not a crash-level issue, post a screenshot of what you get, explanation of the discrepancy and the layout xml and custom class code responsible.